# How can I spy an inner function return value

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I'm doing some integration testing, and I wonder how to get some inner function's return value, I thought about using mocks , but there's only get parameters there

example:

```
def foo():
    goo()

def goo():
    return 3

def test():
    with patch(goo) as goo_mock:
        foo()
        assert goo_mock.return_value == 3
```

Comment: @e.s. return_value is a setter.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @e.s. version 2.7, does it work on 3.x?

Comment: @e.s. that's a shame, any way to do it on 2.7?

Comment: oops, i was wrong.  i forgot to run `test()`. it doesn't work. see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that works in python 2.7.10 and 3.6.1 on windows

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from mock import patch
else:
    from unittest.mock import patch

def foo():
    return goo()

def goo():
    return 3

class CaptureValues(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.return_values = []

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        answer = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.return_values.append(answer)
        return answer

def test():
    with patch('__main__.goo', CaptureValues(goo)) as goo_mock:
        x = foo()
        x = foo()
        print(goo_mock.return_values)
        assert goo_mock.return_values == [3, 3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

`return_value` is used for when you want your function to return some arbitrary value so that you can test other parts. Here's a `goo` that takes a long time to calculate.  I've already tested `goo` somewhere else, and i'm really testing the internals of `foo` and I don't want to wait 5 seconds to calculate the true answer that `goo` returns.  (to see the difference, uncomment `slow_test` and watch the exciting countdown)

```
import time
from unittest.mock import patch
def foo(x):
    return goo(x)

def goo(x):
    for sec in range(x, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(sec)
    return x**2

def slow_test():
    x = foo(5)
    assert x == 25

def test():
    with patch('__main__.goo') as goo_mock:
        goo_mock.return_value = 25
        x = foo('who cares')

        assert x == 25

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test()
    # slow_test()
```

Generally, you want to use mocks to create a fake answer from your helper, `goo`. This is to make sure that `foo` works as expected with specific answers from `goo` and/or to test that when you convert data to pass to `goo`, you're passing the correct data.

1. test `goo`
2. test `foo`:

   1. with `mock_goo.assert_called_with()`  make sure you passed `goo` correct values
   2. set `mock_goo.return_value` to test `foo` with various values returned from `goo`